# ACE Macro Definition Error

Tags: c++, gcc, ace

I'm having difficulty expanding an ACE logging macro. This is an elementary problem but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I'm attempting to formulate my own ACE logging macro with variable argument list. My compiler (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)) supports the `__VA_ARGS__` standard. My current definition is as follows:

```
#define ERROR_PREFIX            ACE_TEXT("ERROR (%T)%?%I")
#define ERROR(FMT,...) ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, ACE_TEXT(FMT) __VA_ARGS__))
```

Which I would like to call via this calling sequence:

```
ERROR( "This is an example error in file %s\n", errorString.c_str() )
```

But I end up with the following compile error:

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘errorString’
```

How best should I modify my macro definition to combat this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with ACE, but it *appears* that you are looking for the comma-deletion extension:

```
#define ERROR(FMT, ...) ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, ACE_TEXT(FMT), ##__VA_ARGS__))
```

As described in [the 'Variadic Macros' section of the GNU CPP manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), putting `##` in between a comma and `__VA_ARGS__` has the special effect of removing the comma if and only if the macro was invoked with zero variable arguments.  Thus,

```
ERROR("This is an example error");
ERROR("This is an example error %s", string);
```

will respectively expand to

```
ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, ACE_TEXT("This is an example error")));
ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, ACE_TEXT("This is an example error %s"), string));
```

which is *probably* what you want (again, I don't know ACE).  Spacing in and around the three-token sequence `, ## __VA_ARGS__` does not matter unless you care about portability to *very old* GCC, as in pre-EGCS.

This feature is a GNU extension, also supported by clang and anything that uses the EDG front end with its GNU compatibility mode enabled.  Crucially, it is *not* supported by Microsoft's compilers as far as I know.

(Since it's almost Christmas, I should also mention that putting spaces on the inside of your parentheses makes the baby Jesus cry.)